Any two disjoint subsets in a family of subsets intersect, prove that any maximal such family of subsets must contain $2^{n-1}$ subsets
Here is the problem: Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of subsets of an $n$-element set $X$ with the property that any two members of $\mathcal{F}$ meet, i.e., $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ for all $A, B \in \mathcal{F}$. Suppose also that no other subset of $X$ meets all of the members of $\mathcal{F}$. Prove that $|\mathcal{F}|=2^{n-1}$.
Please help me out, here is my progress: Observe that if a singleton set $\{ x \}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$, then it forces every single subset of $X$ that contains $x$ to be in $\mathcal{F}$. There are $2^{n-1}$ such subsets. Fine! Suppose no singleton set $\{x \}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. Then its complement $X / \{ x \}$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. Say a two element subset $\{ x, y \}$ of $X$ belongs to $\mathcal{F}$. Then each subset in $\mathcal{F}$ must contain either $x$ or $y$ or both. The number of subsets containing $x$ and $y$ are $2^{n-1}$. Now I am stuck considering sets which contain either $x$ or $y$ but not both.
Edit: I understand why $|\mathcal{F}| \leq 2^{n-1}$: Observe that if $Z \in \mathcal{F}$ then $\overline{Z} \not\in \mathcal{F}$.

Note that if $A\in {\cal F}$ and $A\subset B$ then $B\in{\cal F}$ because $B$ meets all the members of $\cal F$

Isn't this false for $n\geq 2,$ by taking $\mathcal{F} = {X} ?$

You seem to be on the right track, so I'll give you a hint first:
For any set $A$, you can prove that either $A$ or its complement $B=X\setminus A$ must be in $\cal{F}$.

So, here is the proof.
For any set $A\subset X$, let $B=X\setminus A$ be its complement.
As already noted, they cannot both be in $\cal{F}$ as $A\cup B=\emptyset$.
If $A\notin\cal{F}$ and we assume $\cal{F}$ is maximal, there must be some set $U\in\cal{F}$ so that $A\cup U=\emptyset$: otherwise we could have added $A$ to $\cal{F}$. However, that makes $U\subset B$. Since $U$ has nonempty intersection with every other set in $\cal{F}$, then so must $B$, which means $B$ could have been added to $\cal{F}$: ie $\cal{F}$ was not maximal to start with.
Since for every pair $A, B$ of complementary sets, exactly one is in $\cal{F}$, it must contain exactly half the subsets of $X$, ie $2^{n-1}$.
